# "Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Apple, IBM, Oracle, Amazon" split the string at the comma using the split() command

Tags: python-3.x

Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Apple, IBM, Oracle, Amazon" split the  given string at the comma using the split() command in python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: I voted to close this question because no question is being asked

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.split(",")` or a variation of this -

```
s = "Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Apple, IBM, Oracle, Amazon"
output = s.split(", ")
print(output)
```

```
['Facebook', 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'Oracle', 'Amazon']
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

Comment: Glad to help. feel free to mark the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
some_string = "Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Apple, IBM, Oracle, Amazon"
x = some_string.split(',')
print(x)
```